# What is a correct way to run multiple threads that do different jobs in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to build a network related program in Java. I have previous experience with C. In C, when you run thread, you define which method you want it to be run as a thread.

However, in Java, it seems that thread always runs with method `run()` and there can be 1 method with that name in each class.

I want to have at least 2 threads, one thread for working on calculations, and one thread to work on communications with other applications.  (Even if this can be done with 1 thread, I just want to know what would be a correct way to run 2 threads that does totally different jobs)

Below is just a sample code how I implemented the thread. If thread generated by below codes does communication, what would be a nice way to create another thread that does calculation?

```
public class Server implements Runnable{

    static Thread myThread;


    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myThread = new Thread(new Server());
    }


}
```

Comment: What kinds of "communications with other apps" are you talking about?  Depending on what you mean, I'd like to see the answers about that.

Comment: Only a tip: If you need the thread return a value or throws exception, you can use the Callable interface instead of Runnable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put a `main` method in the class that implements `Thread` or `Runnable`. You *could* implement what you want with your current `Server` implementation, but I don't see a good reason to do so. Separate out the concerns, and KISS:

- One boring, simple class with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method
- One `Server implements Runnable` class (one type of thread)
- One `Calculations implements Runnable` class (the other type of thread)

The class with the `main` method would start the `Server` and `Calculations` threads.

Comment: I now get the idea. Java is also convenient as well.

Comment: By the way, how can I fetch the result from Calculation thread if that runs in different class?? Is it possible for thread to have return value? Would you mind giving me a topic which I have to study for? This is interesting..

Comment: Luke, use [The Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) to create a thread pool containing a single thread.  Submit [`Callable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects to this `Executor`, where each instance will perform one of your calculations.  A [`Future`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object is returned that can be used to fetch the result of the calculation.  The calculation itself will be running in a thread managed by the Executor.